# Complete a SQL "INSERT INTO" Command using Gridview and

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to complete a SQL "INSERT INTO" Command using Gridview.

I am using `FindControl` to capture a textbox on the footer: 
`TextBox Tempcol1 = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TBInsertFootercol1"));`

Then bind it to the `InsertParameter` in `SqlDataSource1`:

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["@col1"].DefaultValue = Tempcol1.Text;
```

Then send it to `SqlDataSource1`:

```
SqlDataSource1.Insert();
```

aspx

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
    runat="server"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    DataKeyNames="idt"
    showfooter="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="idt" HeaderText="idt" Readonly="true" SortExpression="idt" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="datetime" HeaderText="datetime" SortExpression="datetime" />
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="col1" HeaderText="col1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("col1") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:textbox id="col1TextBox" text='<%#Bind("col1")%>' runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TBInsertFootercol1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="col2" HeaderText="col2">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("col2") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:textbox id="col2TextBox" text='<%#Bind("col2")%>' runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TBInsertFootercol2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="col3" HeaderText="col3">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("col3") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:textbox id="col3TextBox" text='<%#Bind("col3")%>' runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TBInsertFootercol3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Row Total">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtrowtot" BackColor="LightGreen" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btn_InsertInto" runat="server" Text="Insert Into" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>    </asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource
    id="SqlDataSource1"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Total %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [test];"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [test] [datetime], [col1], [col2], [col3] VALUES @datetime, @col1, @col2, @col3;"
    runat="server">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="datetime" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="col1" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="col2" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="col3" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

aspx.cs

```
 public void btn_InsertInto(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox Tempcol1 = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TBInsertFootercol1"));
        TextBox Tempcol2 = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TBInsertFootercol2"));
        TextBox Tempcol3 = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TBInsertFootercol3"));
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["@datetime"].DefaultValue = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["@col1"].DefaultValue = Tempcol1.Text;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["@col2"].DefaultValue = Tempcol2.Text;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["@col3"].DefaultValue = Tempcol3.Text;
        SqlDataSource1.Insert();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: Why does it do nothing.  It does not Insert Into another row with values I added.  No error statement at all.

Comment: Debug your code, put breakpoint at `SqlDataSource1.Insert();` and when fired check value of `SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters` one by one, see if they have value or not, then tell us, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the '@' from the InsertParamters Statements

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["datetime"].DefaultValue = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["col1"].DefaultValue = Tempcol1.Text;
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["col2"].DefaultValue = Tempcol2.Text;
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["col3"].DefaultValue = Tempcol3.Text;
```